# Windows mutex WAIT_OBJECT_0 and WAIT_ABANDONED

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I don't understand what is the difference in a multithread program between doing :

```
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
// Critical secontion here
ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
```

to do something more complex like in the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927.aspx):

```
dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
            ghMutex,    // handle to mutex
            INFINITE);  // no time-out interval

switch (dwWaitResult) 
{
    // The thread got ownership of the mutex
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
        __try { 
            // TODO: Write to the database
            printf("Thread %d writing to database...\n", 
                GetCurrentThreadId());
            dwCount++;
        } 
        __finally { 
            // Release ownership of the mutex object
            if (! ReleaseMutex(ghMutex)) 
            { 
                // Handle error.
            } 
        } 
        break; 

    // The thread got ownership of an abandoned mutex
    // The database is in an indeterminate state
    case WAIT_ABANDONED: 
        return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: The first example is assuming `WaitForSingleObject` succeeds, the second allows for the fact that it may fail.

Comment: @JonathanPotter when can WaitForSingleObject fail when passing a mutex handle to it ?

Comment: MSDN doesn't have bigger weapons than FALSE,  all they can do is upper-case it.  WAIT_ABANDONED is appropriately upper-cased, it is a *nasty* bug in your code that you always want to know about.  Make lots and lots of noise.  Don't hesitate RaiseException.  Like the dbase provider did.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure that I've understood you.

Comment: I'll have to work on a much bigger answer, David's post is an inspiration to do something about that.  When I'll find the time.

Comment: Actually, the second one doesn't handle `WAIT_ABANDONED`, just leaving the mutex locked and expecting other code to deal with it. The first one does, perform operations under the protection of the mutex and then releasing it.

Comment: It can fail in the way described in the example, i.e., because the mutex was abandoned.  It can fail because the mutex handle isn't actually valid.  It might even fail because the system is critically low on memory (I'm not sure, but the documentation doesn't promise that it won't) or for some reason nobody has thought of before.  The point is that *you need to do error checking even if you don't know exactly what errors you're expecting*.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: An invalid handle will result in an WAIT_FAILED which isn't handled in any of the two cases here.

Comment: @Arno: good point; so neither sample handles errors properly!

Comment: It's true that neither example handles errors properly, but importantly the second example only operates on the protected data if the mutex was acquired safely.

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer, but the first example assumes that `WaitForSingleObject` succeeds, while the second example handles (some of the) errors.  More importantly, in the second example the code will only operate on the protected data if the mutex was acquired *safely*, meaning the data is (theoretically) in a known state.

`WaitForSingleObject` could return two possible errors here: `WAIT_ABANDONED` or `WAIT_FAILED`:

- `WAIT_FAILED` could happen if, say, your Mutex has been closed, in which case you likely have an error in your software.  In cases like these, you could log the fact that it's happened and try to exit as cleanly as possible.
- `WAIT_ABANDONED` means that a thread holding the Mutex has exited *or been killed*.  Either way your program is in an unknown state, the data being protected is in an unknown state, and you should probably exit as cleanly as possible... just don't touch the data, as you can't safely do so.

Remember that a `WAIT_ABANDONED` could result from someone opening up your process in a debugger (or something like Process Explorer) and killing a thread, not just from your own programs error... so you need to handle it.  I guess the same could cause `WAIT_FAILED` too... so handle that as well.

Comment: And what if it is a program that I would prefer that people won't debug ? It's better not to check for these errors ?

Comment: @Omlis532: You should always check for these errors. I mentioned debugger as an example... I could kill a thread in your process using Process Explorer. If I did that then yes, it's my fault if I ended up with corrupt data, but if your program detects something like that has happened, and try to die gracefully.  There could be lots of reasons for an abandoned mutex, and if you get it you will not know what state your protected data is in.